# Enhanced eCommerce tracking - product variables not passing through to GA

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

[image][image]I am doing some enhanced eCommerce tracking. I've had my developer do a data layer push for each eCommerce checkout stage (eg detail view, add to cart). The data layer syntax follows Google's data layer format requirements.

My tag (eg product added to cart) is firing and the event (eg product added it cart) is passing through correctly to Google Analytics. However, the product variables (eg brand, category) that go along with the ecomerce event (eg add to cart) are not passing through to Google Analytics correctly. My GTM tag and trigger set up is correct as far as I can tell, I have enabled enhanced e-commerce features and checked yes to use the data layer.

I've used the Google Analytics debug chrome extension and checked to see all the product variables are coming through in the developer console, as recommended by Simo on his blog. The variables are coming through but there is a line saying 'No tags fired for event: eec.detail' which may be my key to the problem.

I'm really not sure why my product variables are not passing through to GA, I have spent 7-8 hours trying to figure this out, checking my GTM set up and combing through the data layer. I would really appreciate any advice! I am a bit limited in screenshots etc that I can share as site info is confidential.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't push info before sending the pageview but you do it through an event (where in the case of the add to the cart is inevitable) you need a trigger to activate it.

In the case of your screenshot, you need an **event** type **trigger** with event name equals '**eec.detail**' that activates the tag that sends the e-commerce information to Google Analytics.